# Meaning of SccNumberOfProjects in a Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I'm comparing two solution files and I find a strange difference between them. They both build properly, and source control seems to work. I'd like to believe that I'm seeing a difference that makes no difference, but I need some help convincing myself.

In

```
Global
    GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
```

one of the solutions has

```
        SccNumberOfProjects = 25
```

and the other has

```
        SccNumberOfProjects = 26
```

The solution with the "26" has a section

```
    SccProjectUniqueName25 = SomethingTests\\SomethingTests.csproj
    SccProjectName25 = SomethingTests
    SccLocalPath25 = SomethingTests
```

but the solution with "25" ends with "SccProjectUniqueName24".

In both cases, the SomethingTests project exists in the solution when opened by Visual Studio.

Also, I looked with File->Source Control->Change Source Control, and found that in both cases, the project in question is bound to the same server, at the correct location in source control, is Connected, and the Status is "Valid"!

So, if anyone actually *knows* that the "Scc" section is redundant information, or something to that effect, then please let me know, and please let me know where that's documented.

Comment: As a fast solution, I guess you can just [delete the duplicate one](http://goo.gl/Bjtw7). For what it is and why it is there, the closest thing I could find is the [source control plug-ins API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166170.aspx) of Visual Studio but even there, `SccNumberOfProjects` is not mentioned. I for one hate when my solution and project files are affected in the name of source control, so I'm glad I ditched TFS for Git.